# How to map and retrieve data at index 0 in Nest JS?

Tags: sql-server, mapping, nestjs

Here is my code:

```
export class DependantsService {

  constructor(            
    private sequelize: Sequelize
  ) { }

    async showDependants(EmpId: string): Promise<any> {
        var response: dtoDependants = new dtoDependants();
        var data = await this.sequelize.query('Exec API_Select_EmployeeDependants :EmployeeId',
          {
            replacements: { EmployeeId: EmpId},
            type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
          });
          if(data.length>0){

             data.map((item: any) => {  
              response.employeeId=item.EmployeeId;
              response.Id=item.Id;
              response.fullname=item.Fullname;
              response.relationship=item.Relationship;
              response.gender=item.Gender;
              response.maritalstatus=item.MaritalStatus;
              response.dob=item.DOB;
              response.nic=item.NIC;
    
             });
    
          return response;
          }

    }
}
```

Now there are 2 records in the SQL Server database and it is returning the last one. If I only do
`return data;`
It returns both the records in the database. I want to somehow **map** values at index 0,1, etc. and then
`return response;`
so that i can get any of the records i like from the database. I have tried using
`data[Object.keys(data)[0]]` but it doesn't work and return a 500 error. Any help would be appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: `return data[0]` ?

Comment: @TobiasS. the point is that ```return data[Object.keys(data)[0]];``` and ```return data[0];``` both are working fine. But i want to somehow **map** values like with the above **responses**. and that is not happening. I have tried  ```data[Object.keys(data)[0]].map((item: any) =>``` It runs but the output is 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
if(data.length > 0) {
  return {  
    employeeId: data[0].EmployeeId,
    Id: data[0].Id,
    fullname: data[0].Fullname,
    relationship: data[0].Relationship,
    gender: data[0].Gender,
    maritalstatus: data[0].MaritalStatus,
    dob: data[0].DOB,
    nic: data[0].NIC    
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. But it gives error: **Property 'EmployeeId' does not exist on type 'object'**

Comment: well is there even a column named EmployeeId?

Comment: Yes, my code provided in the question runs fine, but it just returns the last record automatically, where as there are 2 records. And I want the records by index.